# How to Add $_GET['data'] in URL (media.php?data=123) when I choose data from dropdownlist?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am developing a project which is i have a website in php and database in mysql. I have linked them well. Now i have combobox in which i have populated it with the data from database.

this is my "select" scripts :

```
<script>
 jQuery(".asdasd").on("change", function () {
        var url_to_append = $(this).find(":selected").text();
        var val = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        //if above dont work try this var val =$('select[name="day"]').val();
        window.location.href = "yourURL?"+url_to_append+"="+val;

    });
 </script>

<td><select class="form-control input-sm mb-md" name="day">
        <option value=0 selected>- Day -</option>
    <?php
    $q = mysql_query("select * from t_day");
    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($q)){ 
        echo "<option value=$row1[kd_day] required\>$row1[day]</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select></td>
```

fyi: $row1[kd_day] value is (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday)

Now the problem is, on selecting any value from the combobox, the data i choose should be updated in address bar (auto-refresh with selected value).

example_1 : when i choose "Friday" from dropdownlist, the page refreshed and URL will become www.mydomain.com/index.php?days=friday

example_2 : when i choose "Sunday" from dropdownlist, the page refreshed and URL will become www.mydomain.com/index.php?days=sunday,

how to make it ?

Comment: you want to load the page again on each dropdown change ?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @SumitPandey yes sir.

Comment: @Epodax im sorry, i only tried editing my "select" script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use jquery

```
$(".input-sm").on("change", function () {
        window.location.href = "www.mydomain.com/index.php?days="+$(this).find(":selected").text();

    });
```

or you can try having anchor tags in your options like (not sure it will work)

```
echo "<option value=$row1[kd_day] required\><a href='www.mydomain.com/index.php?days='.$row1[day]>$row1[day]</a></option>";
```

Comment: i updated my code based on your example, but still not working.

Comment: did you get any errors? I just tried in jsfiddle and it worked

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
  jQuery(".input-sm mb-md").on("change", function () {
        var url_to_append = $(this).find(":selected").text();
        var val = $(this).find(":selected").val();
        //if above dont work try this var val =$('select[name="day"]').val();
        window.location.href = "yourURL?"+url_to_append+"="+val;

    });
```

Comment: i updated my code based on your example, but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Another clean solution would be...

```
<select class="form-control input-sm mb-md" name="day" onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
 <option value="#">- Day -</option>
 <option value="http://website.com/?days=monday">Monday</option>
 <option value="http://website.com/?days=tuesday">Tuesday</option>
</select>
```

Now you have to put the names dynamically from PHP.

I suggest you to create the `$q` on the top of the page and to use:

```
while (expression):
// do stuff
endwhile;
```

This way it is more readable. (personal opinion)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this I think it will very easy solution and hope it will work for you.

```
<td><select class="form-control input-sm mb-md" name="day" onchange="gotoSelect(this.value)">
    <option value=0 selected>- Day -</option>
<?php
$q = mysql_query("select * from t_day");
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($q)){ 

    if(isset($_REQUEST['day']) && $_REQUEST['day'] == $row1[kd_day]){

        echo "<option value=$row1[kd_day] required\ selected='selected'>$row1[day]</option>";

    }else{
        echo "<option value=$row1[kd_day] required\>$row1[day]</option>";   
    }
}
?>
</select></td>  

<script >
function gotoSelect(day)
{
    if(day != '0'){
        var url = "http://yourdomain.com?day="+val;
        location.replace(url);
    }
}
</script>
```

please try this.